# Can i read through an Argument that is a generic list?

Tags: c#, generic-list, postsharp

I am using postsharp to log method call and i need to log the parameter values also.
my problem comes in when i have parameters that are generic lists and i cant iterate through the list to get the values in it.

i know how to check if the parameter is a list but i just cant read through the values in it...

is it possible to read through the list and how would i go about doing this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.Arguments.Count; i++)
            {
                if (methodName == "LogonUser" && i == 1)
                {
                    sb.Append(",********");
                    break;
                }
                else if (i > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(", ");
                }

                if (args.Arguments[i] is IList && args.Arguments[i].GetType().IsGenericType)
                {

                   //here is where i need to read through the list


                }
                sb.Append(args.Arguments.GetArgument(i) ?? "null");




            }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you having trouble with? What does your code look like, what is your parameter type etc?

Comment: Can you please post your PostSharp asset code?

Comment: basically all i want to do is read through the values in a parameter that is a generic list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to iterate through the argument, when its a (generic) list you can
check the argument if it implements the interface IEnumerable and then loop the values
in the list with a foreach statement.

```
IEnumerable argumentList = args.Arguments[i] as IEnumerable;

if (argumentList != null) {
  foreach(var item in argumentList){
    // Do what you want with the item
  }
}
```